# UK visitors visas

Tags: visas

My husband is a British citizen and my kids and I have South African passports. We want to travel to London for a few days. What type of visa should I apply for and is there costs involved with my husband being a British citizen?

Comment: The answer is different if you all live in an EU country other than the UK.  Should we assume that you do not?  Also, if your husband is the father of your children (including if he has legally adopted them, though I am less familiar with that), they may be British citizens.  You may want to clear that up before applying for visas.

Comment: My wife is British and I am South African - we live in the USA. I apply for the standard visitor visa every time we travel over to the UK to visit my in-laws, so I'd imagine it would be the same for you. There are no extra costs, but make sure it's very obvious in your application that you intend to leave the UK and not overstay...

Comment: If you live in the EU, the EEA, or Switzerland, please respond to this comment and I will reopen the question.

Comment: We live in Ireland